# WalletAppKit creates an address every time Bitcoinj gets initialized

Tags: bitcoinj, java, android

I'm implementing an app using BitcoinJ, but every time I run the code, a new address is created. Is there any way to work with the very first address that was created and stop creating new addresses?

```
walletAppKit = new WalletAppKit(parameters, walletDir, "my_wallet") {
        @Override
        protected void onSetupCompleted() {

        if (wallet().getImportedKeys().size() < 1) 
           wallet().importKey(new ECKey());
           walletAppKit.peerGroup().setBloomFilterFalsePositiveRate(0.00001);
           setupWalletListeners(wallet());

           for (Address address: wallet().getIssuedReceiveAddresses()){
                Log.d("myLogs", address.toBase58());
           }
        }
    };
walletAppKit.setBlockingStartup(false);
walletAppKit.setUserAgent("RocketWallet", "1.0");
walletAppKit.startAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.14.2/index.html?org/bitcoinj/wallet/Wallet.html):

> getImportedKeys() returns a list of the non-deterministic keys that
>   have been imported into the wallet, or the empty list if none.

Try to change:

```
if (wallet().getImportedKeys().size() < 1)
    wallet().importKey(new ECKey());
```

to:

```
if (wallet().getIssuedReceiveKeys().size() < 1)
    wallet().freshReceiveKey();
```

To get the first address in your wallet, you can use:

```
wallet.getIssuedReceiveKeys().get(0).toAddress(TestNet3Params.get()).toBase58().toString();
```